# How to use ASP.NET Identity 2.0 to register new users from mobile

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I have an ASP MVC project with Identity 2.0 where users can sign up and register via the website through the Account Controller.  I have a complimentary Android application where I want to access the same Account/Register post method.

I've tried creating a post method directly to /account/register, but I get an error that

"The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present."

How can I adapt my existing account controller to allow the /account/register post to work from a non html client?

Thank you.

Comment: Either create a new controller method or remove anti forgery token attribute. But I suggest creating a new controller method.

Comment: Making a new controller without the antiforgery token makes sense.  I would just copy/paste the code over from the existing register method?  Do you have any recommendations in terms of security?

Comment: Yes you can just copy paste from existing method to new controller.For your android client you can implement token based system, while registering an user they need to provide a token (that they can retrieve before making the request) with the post body. There is a nice article as how to implement token based system using OWIN http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Answer (score 0):

I think creating a new controller without anti forgery token attribute should do it. But I strongly suggest that for mobile clients you do a token based authentication system. Here is an excellent which explains step by step how to do that. http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/